# behaviour of prime ideals dividing discriminant

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

If $\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathcal{O}_k$ is a  prime ideal, and $M/L/k$ is a Galois extension tower such that $\mathfrak{p}|\mathcal{N}_{L/k}(c_{M/L}),$ where $c_{M/L}$ is the conductor of $M/L$. Is it true that if we know that $\mathfrak{p}$ splits completely in $L$ then all the primes that lie above $\mathfrak{p}$ divide the conductor, and why?

We may assume that $L/k$ and $M/L$ are abelian extensions, though $M/k$ need not be abelian.

Comment: What does conductor mean if the extensions aren't abelian?

Comment: You are assuming that $M$ and $L$ are Galois (and finite, presumably) over $K$. If follows that the extensions $M/L/K$ are preserved by the action of $G = \mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$, and in particular, $c_{M/L}$ is fixed by $G$. But $G$ acts transitively on the primes $\mathfrak{P}$ of $L$ above $\mathfrak{p}$ in $K$. So if $c_{M/L}$ is divisible by one $\mathfrak{P}$, it is divisible by all such primes. The same conclusion holds with $c_{M/L}$ replaced by the relative discriminant $\Delta_{M/L}$ and with no assumption that $M/L$ or $L/K$ is abelian.